# Node.js How To serialize colon separated key value pairs to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Given (as a post response body):

```
RESULT: OK
RESULT_PS: FINISHED
RESULT_CODE: 000
```

I need to serialize it to json, I use node's [request](https://github.com/request/request) to get this from server.
Surely I can parse it string by string.

1. But isn't there an easier way?
2. Maybe ready serializer or something to serialize such data to JSON?
3. What format is this?

Comment: In any case the optimal structure of this type of text would be an array of ':' separated tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [node.js](https://nodejs.org) there is handy module called [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html):

```
const querystring = require('querystring'),
    payload =
        "RESULT: OK\n\r" +
        "RESULT_PS: FINISHED\n" +
        "RESULT_CODE: 000\n";

let parsed = querystring.parse(payload, '\n', ':', {decodeURIComponent: s =>  s.trim()});

console.log(parsed);
```

For browsers there is a lot of good methods described in answers. Here is another one (vanilla JS):

```js
var payload =
 "RESULT: OK\n\r" +
 "RESULT_PS: FINISHED\n" +
 "RESULT_CODE: 000\n";

var browserParsed = payload.split("\n")
 .map(function (s) {
  return s.trim().split(":");
 })
 .filter(function (s) {
  return s.length && s.length > 1;
 })
 .reduce(function (acc, c) {
  acc[ c[ 0 ].trim() ] = c[ 1 ].trim();
  return acc;
 }, {});

console.log(browserParsed);
```

Answer (score 1):

filter each line from following code

```
var jsonObject = {}

function parser(str){
var arr = str.split(":");
jsonObject[arr[0]] = arr[1];
}
```

your final jsonObject is json you needed.

Make sure that you need to pass RESULT: OK, RESULT_PS: FINISHED,RESULT_CODE: 000 as seperate strings from parser.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is just a delimited plain text response. (Where are you getting it from? Transaction response?) However, since it's that simple it's easily parseable with a quick map-reduce operation.

```
function trim(str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}

function nonEmpty(str) {
    return null != str && str.length > 0;
}

function splitKeyValue(row) {
    var tokens = row.split(":").map(trim);

    // My assumption that a row should only contain 2 colon separated tokens
    if (tokens.length > 2) {
        throw new Error("Malformed row: " + row);
    }

    return tokens;
}

function merge(acc, item) {
    // Normalise key to lower case, to guarantee spelling
    acc[item[0].toLowerCase()] = item[1];

    return acc;
}

function parseResponse(payload) {
    return payload.split("\n").
        filter(nonEmpty).
        map(splitKeyValue).
        reduce(merge, {});
}
```

Using the snippet of code above, the result should be:

```
var payload = 
    "RESULT: OK\n" +
    "RESULT_PS: FINISHED\n" +
    "RESULT_CODE: 000\n";

var parsed = parseResponse(payload);

console.log(parsed);

// Output:
// {
//   result: "OK",
//   result_ps: "FINISHED",
//   result_code: "000"
// }

// Each separate field is then accessible from it's name

console.log(parsed.result); // Output: "OK"
```

Comment: Transaction response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, didn't find any ready solution.
So wrote this function:

```
parseResponse = function(response) {
    var result = { };

    response.replace(/([^\s:]+)\s*:\s*([^\n\s]+)/gi, function() {
        var key = arguments[1], value = decodeURIComponent(arguments[2]);
        result[key] = !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value) ? parseFloat(value) : value;
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: If the value has a space in it, this solution truncates the value at the space

Comment: Fair note, there should've been no values with spaces inside by the spec of the response I was parsing.